# Creating and returning structure in C

Tags: c, c99

I have a question about creating and allocating space for structures and what is a "better" way of doing it.

Let's say we have bunch of parameters and based on them we want to create a structure. Not directly store all the parameters, but somehow process them and store the values.

Example:

```
typedef struct {
  int op;
  int res;
} Result;


int operation = 0; // 0 = addition, 1 = multiplication
int a = 2, int b = 3;
Result r;
r.op = operation;
if (operation == 0) {
  r.res = a+b;
else if(operation == 1) {
  r.res = a*b;
else {
 ...etc...
}
```

These operations can be more complicated than this and there could be many more parameters that define the final structure.
So I want to create a function

```
create_structure(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn) {
  switch(arg1) {
    case 0: struct_function0(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    case 1: struct_function1(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    ...
    case m: struct_functionm(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
  }
}
```

and all these functions can have can have a similar structure as “create_structure” and would form “function creation tree” where we always choose one branch based on parameters until we reach some function that will finally create our structure.
We also want "root" of the tree to return a pointer to the place of memory where this structure is stored.

The question is that how to return the created structure from the "leaf" of the function creation tree.

The first option is to always return the structure from the inner functions and then in the root of the tree allocate memory for that structure and memcpy all the contents:

```
MyStruct* create_structure(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn) {
  MyStruct s;
  switch(arg1) {
    case 0: s = struct_function0(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    case 1: s = struct_function1(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    ...
    case m: s = struct_functionm(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
  }

  MyStruct* p_s = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
  memcpy(p_s, &s, sizeof(MyStruct));
  return p_s
}
```

The other possibility would be having the pointer to the struct in the root, mallocing it and then sending it as an argument to all the "branches" of the tree. Like this

```
MyStruct* create_structure(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn) {
  MyStruct* p_s = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
  switch(arg1) {
    case 0: struct_function0(p_s, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    case 1: struct_function1(p_s, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    ...
    case m: struct_functionm(p_s, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
  }

  return p_s;
}
```

In the second variant, we would be passing argument p_s through all the functions in the tree until we reach a leaf. 
There is a possible third option where malloc could be in the leaves of the tree.

Which of these possibilities is preferred? Is there any other option?

Comment: What prevents you from using `MyStruct create_structure(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn) {
  MyStruct s; ... return s; }`. It is legal to return a `struct` in C language...

Comment: Why do you need a big `switch`?  Can you just select from an array of function pointers?

Answer (score 3):

I would let the caller decide how to allocate MyStruct so the caller know if or how to deallocate.

```
void create_structure(MyStruct *s, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn) {
  switch(arg1) {
    case 0: struct_function0(s, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    case 1: struct_function1(s, arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
  }
}

MyStruct s;
create_structure(&s, 1,2,3);
```

or

```
MyStruct *s2 = malloc(sizeof *s2);
create_structure(s2, 1,2,3);

free(s2);
```

Comment: The point of my question was if I should pass `MyStruct *` deep into the tree. (The tree can be arbitrarily deep)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need malloc at all. One possibility is to pass pointer to struct to all functions

```
void create_structure(MyStruct* s, arg1, ...)
{
...
}
MyStruct p_s;
create_structure(&s, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

You can also return a copy of your structure, if size of structure is small then it is not heavy operation.

```
MyStruct create_structure(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn) {
  MyStruct p_s;
  switch(arg1) {
    case 0: p_s = struct_function0(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    case 1: p_s = struct_function1(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
    ...
    case m: p_s = struct_functionm(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn); break;
  }
  return p_s;
}
```

Comment: I would adopt this solution, and also use function pointers instead of the switch(...), to tend towards "C style" polymorphism.

Comment: Yes. In real code I am using function pointers. But for readability purposes now I used a switch.